# How to show $a+b+ad\geq c+d+bc$ given $a\geq c$ and $a+b\geq c+d$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $0\leq a,b,c,d\leq 1$ and $a\geq c$ and $a+b\geq c+d$. Show that $a+b+ad\geq c+d+bc.$

Of course we have $a+b\geq c+d$, but how to relate $ad$ and $bc$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $x=a+b$ and $y=c+d$. Then the main inequality changes into:
$$
x+a(y-c)\geq y+c(x-a)\implies (a-1)y\geq (c-1)x
$$
but the last inequality is trivial given that $a,c<1$ and $x,y>0$ and also $x>y$ and $a>c$. Indeed, $x>y>0$ and $0>a-1>c-1$ and therefore by multiplying two inequalities we can get the final result.

Comment: +1: Nice solution!

Comment: I'd rewrite the inequality to be proved as $(1-c)x\ge(1-a)y$, so you have less problems with negative numbers and reversal of inequalities. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Set $a=c+h_1$ and $b=d+h_2$.

Then, $a\geq c\iff h_1\geq0$

and 
 $a+b\geq c+d\iff h_1+h_2\geq0$.

Then, \begin{align}
\\& a+b+ad\geq c+d+bc
\\\iff& h_1+h_2\geq bc-ad=(d+h_2)c-(c+h_1)d=cd+ch_2-cd-h_1d
\\\iff& h_1+h_2\geq ch_2-dh_1
\\\iff&h_1+dh_1+h_2(1-c)\geq0
\end{align}

Note that $0\leq1-c\leq1$.

Now, if $h_2\geq0$ then indeed, $h_1+dh_1+h_2(1-c)\geq0$ since all the terms are positive.

If $h_2<0$, then $h_1+dh_1+h_2(1-c)\geq h_1+dh_1+h_2\geq0$ since $h_1+h_2\geq0$ and $d\geq0$.

Comment: How did you get this inequality $$h_1+dh_1+h_2(1-c)\geqslant h_1+dh_1+h_2$$

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع That's because $h_2(1-c)$ is most negative when $(1-c)$ is maximum ($=1$).
Alternatively, multiply both sides of $1-c\leq1$ by the positive number $-h_2$.

Comment: You're being right, good answer! +1